# Tab without internal scroll

Tags: android

I have a ContenView with a LinearLayout containing a few TextViews and then a TabHost.
The TabHost has 3 tabs which may contain a ListActivity with many items, and thus require scrolling.

Currently the FrameLayout automatically gets a vertical scrollbar, but I want to have a scrollbar on the main view.

Ie. when I scroll down to view the rest of the ListActivity in my current tab I want the TextView above the tab to scroll out of sight.

Any ideas?

Take a look at this screenshot I made to clarify.
The left screen is how it currently is. The right one is photoshopped to what I want to achieve.
[image]

---

solved it using a workaround not requiring internal scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot do this with a tabhost. You might want to reconsider how your layout is designed, this is how I would approach this problem:

```
1 ListView with 2 headers
Header 1 : your textviews
Header 2 : 3 tab like buttons
```

With the three tab like buttons you can control the content that is displayed in the list like it is a tabhost. This way the scroll bar will display the way you want it to.